# jQuery Validate: how to change field value on custom method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I'm trying to implement a cryptographic library that should run onto some fields and fill in another, hidden field.

My best bet on this was replicating the default `remote` method, that runs an AJAX call and returns "pending", so jQuery.Validate would wait something for it to submit the form (in case it's valid). That seems to be working fine, as (by using breakpoints) I can indeed identify the correct value in the encrypted field before the page gets actually submitted.

However, it seems the form submit behaviour was already called, and any change to form fields during validation would not bubble up anymore: my backend server still receives the field as empty.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$.validator.addMethod('encrypted', function(value, element, params, message) {
    var validator = this;
    var errors = {};
    //gets the other field names from params and mingles stuff
    $.post(params.url, { data: data }, {
        success: function(data) {
            element.value = data.value;
            //this here was copied from the `remote` validation method
            var submitted = validator.formSubmitted;
            validator.prepareElement(element);
            validator.formSubmitted = submitted;
            validator.successList.push(element);
            delete validator.invalid[element.name];
            validator.showErrors();
        }
    });
    return 'pending';
};

$('form').validate({
    token: { encrypted: { fields: [/*...*/] }
});
```

Is there a way to change the field value during validation?

Comment: Define "during validation"?  You mean after the submit button is clicked but before the form is submitted?

Comment: yeah, @Sparky. During the proccess of validation that the plugin runs.

Comment: You have two options.  `submitHandler` is fired after the button is clicked and the form is valid.  `invalidHandler` is fired after the button is clicked and the form is invalid.  Otherwise, [the other options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) fire based on the validity of the field being considered at that moment.  There is no single option or callback that says "whole form is being validated and we don't yet know the outcome".

Comment: Still don't fully understand why you'd want to change the value of an input *during* validation.

Comment: the idea was to run a piece of code that would fill in a hidden input given some other fields are filled in (and based on their values).
As this kind of behaviour is used (manually) through my team, I wanted to create a custom method so we can all implement jQuery Validate with an easy-to-use custom method.
I'll take a look at using `submitHandler`, but I think I would fall in the same issue: changing the field value wouldn't make the new value be sent.

Comment: another reason for that happening ideally during validation (as a custom method): the server could reply with an internal validation error and refuse to encrypt the data - this would generate a validation message that we could show with jQuery Validate as well.

Comment: That does not explain at all why you need to change it *during* validation rather than *just before*.

Comment: How is this any different than validating a captcha code against the server?

Comment: because: 1. it depends on other fields to be valid as well; 2. it can generate error messages as a validation method would.
It is different from a captcha in the sense that captcha only returns "valid/not valid". It does not changes form values as well.

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin was not designed for anything like that.  Form data typically does not change during validation, as validation is supposed to be the very last thing to happen before sending the completed form to the server.   You'll probably have to write your own for this.

Comment: if that's not possible, I would like to know at least why the changed value is not sent with the form...

Comment: Likely because the serialized array was already created.